# PNG generated from XML not found in drawable folder

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-appcompat, androidx, android-vectordrawable

I’m working on a project with minSdk 23 and compileSDK 31. I’m seeing an issue when running the app on API 23 where when loading a vector resource via

`ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.vectorID)`

I receive an error

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/vectorID.png`

But I can load the drawable successfully using `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(LocalContext.current, R.drawable.vectorID)`

Looking at the build folder, folders drawable-[x][xx][etc]hdpi are generated with the xml converted to pngs. But there is no -v4 folders generated.

Why are api level 4 folders being generated for a nexus5 api 23 device? Didn't androidx drop all these version tags? Furthermore, any suggestions on how to get around this?

Appcompat version is `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1`

Comment: Just to clarify - what is the resource you are trying to load? Is it vector generated from svg or is it png file?